# R Script to Scrape Links from Website Not Extracting Links

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

This is my first time using R to scrape a webpage for a class project. The R script is not extracting the links from the search results.

Building the R script based on the following tutorial: `https://ladal.edu.au/webcrawling.html#ref-WN17`
R Script:

````
# install packages
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("readtext")
install.packages("webdriver")
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("readtext")
install.packages("flextable")
install.packages("webdriver")
webdriver::install_phantomjs()
# install klippy for copy-to-clipboard button in code chunks
```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("rlesur/klippy")
````

````
    # load packages
    library(tidyverse)
    library(rvest)
    library(readtext)
    library(flextable)
    library(webdriver)
    # activate klippy for copy-to-clipboard button
    klippy::klippy()
    # define url
    url <- ""
    # download content
    webc <- rvest::read_html(url)
    # inspect
    webc
    ```
````

```
#extract only the text from the webpage
{r webtxt, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
webc %>%
  # extract paragraphs
  rvest::html_nodes("p") %>%
  # extract text
  rvest::html_text() -> webtxt
# inspect
head(webtxt)
```

```
#extract the headline
```

```
{r header, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
webc %>%
  # extract paragraphs
  rvest::html_nodes("h1") %>%
  # extract text
  rvest::html_text() -> header
# inspect
head(header)
```

````
    #Run PhantomJS
    
    pjs_instance <- run_phantomjs()
    pjs_session <- Session$new(port = pjs_instance$port)

#Download and parse tag overview page

    ```{r singlepage, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
    url <- ""
    # go to URL
    pjs_session$go(url)
    # render page
    rendered_source <- pjs_session$getSource()
    # download text and parse the source code into an XML object
    html_document <- read_html(rendered_source)
    ```

#Scrape single link from tag overview page

    ```{r extractlinks, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
    links <- html_document %>%
      html_nodes(xpath = "") %>%
      html_attr(name = "href")
    # inspect 
    links
````

````
#Scrape all links from tag overview page
```{r extractlinks, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
links <- html_document %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[contains(@, '')]/a") %>%
  html_attr(name = "href")
# inspect 
links
````

Get the following:

```
[1] "javascript:;" "javascript:;" "javascript:;" "javascript:;" "javascript:;" "javascript:;"
 [7] "javascript:;" "javascript:;" "javascript:;" "javascript:;"
```

The script was not extracting the links from the site. Would really appreciate any help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: So are you trying to get all the links from the search results when you search for the work ukraine? (this page: https://search.news.cn/?lang=en#search/0/ukraine/1/) Or just all the links on the original page? (this page: https://english.news.cn/europe/20230311/c1996d956c5b4a7a903111d90f889ae6/c.html)

Comment: Or are you trying to follow all the scraped links from the first page and then scrape the links from all the secondary pages?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want all the links from each individual news article because they're the pretty much the same for each story, but here's how to do it!

(If you actually want the text from each article, it should be pretty easy to use this approach and just change the html node that you look for in the second loop)

## The Problem

Sometimes the page that packages like `rvest` see is different from the page that the user sees. (Probably some sort of dynamic javascript thing or whatever behind the scenes).

## The Solution

I used `Rselenium` to visit each individual page and see the same thing that a user would. Then I used `rvest` to search for the html nodes for links.

## Warnings

- I did barely anything to avoid blocking. If you scrape a lot of pages very quickly or are scraping a site that's on the lookout for bots, this code will probably get you blocked unless you add a user agent or evasive tactics like random scrolling. (This code worked for me! But don't be surprised if it stops working if you scrape thousands of results.
- **This code is very slow**. Like over an hour slow. I did this on purpose as a lazy way to avoid getting blocked and because I assumed this would be the sort of thing that you can run overnight and check again in the morning. To speed it up, either scrape fewer pages of results by changing the `last_page` term, or speed up each loop iteration by reducing the number of seconds inside `Sys.sleep()`.

## The code

```
# load required libraries

library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# Define search parameters ----------------------------------------------------

# Let's start by assuming you want the first ten pages of results
# To increase the number change the last_page value

first_page <- 1
last_page <- 10

# this is the word you want to search for
search_term <- "ukraine"

# this is the language you want the results to be in 
# in this case English
search_language <- "en"

# this creates a vector of search result pages:
# first_page:last_page is a way of creating a sequence of numbers in R
# same as this: 1:10

search_results_urls <- paste0("http://search.news.cn/?lang=",
                              search_language,
                              "#search/0/",
                              search_term,
                              "/",
                              first_page:last_page)


# find all the links on the search results pages ------------------------------

## rvest doesn't work---------------------------------------------------------

# This doesn't work, which means that the page that rvest sees isn't the same 
# as what we see when we navigate to that page, so let's try RSelenium instead

first_results_html <- search_results_urls[1] %>% read_html()


first_results_html %>% 
    html_node("body") %>% 
    html_node("#search-result") 

# This also doesn't work
first_results_html %>% 
  html_nodes("a")


## RSelenium -------------------------------------------------------------------

# RSelenium is sometimes hard to set up in R. Assuming RSelenium actually starts
# up correctly, here's a way to use it to get the links: 

### set up RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]



### Loop through the first ten pages of results ------------------------------

# Define an empty dataframe for later 
# This isn't best practice, because it's slow, but whatever hahaha
all_results <- data.frame(page = "remove",
                          links = "remove",
                          titles = "remove")


for(i in first_page:last_page){
  
# navigate to the ith url  
remDr$navigate(search_results_urls[i])

# pull the html from the ith page
search_results_html_sel <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] 

# read the html
# find links (html tag for links is "a")
# pull the href attribute from each link

links <- search_results_html_sel %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") 

# read the html
# find links (html tag for links is "a")
# pull the text associated with each link (in this case the article title)


titles <- search_results_html_sel %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_text()

# now let's make a dataframe of titles + links

full_page_results <- data.frame(page= i,
                                links,
                                titles)

# now let's filter our data frame to only include links to news stories



full_page_results <- full_page_results %>%
  filter(str_detect(links, "english.news.cn/."))

all_results <- rbind(all_results, full_page_results)

#these steps are to reduce the risk of getting blocked because they think you're 
# a bot, this is definitely not going to be enough
# for a lot of results/ a website on the lookout for bots


Sys.sleep(7)


}

# remove the first row
all_results <- all_results[-1,]



### Loop through each news article to find secondary links ------------------------------

all_articles <- data.frame(page = "remove",
                           article_title = "remove",
                           article_link = "remove",
                           in_article_links = "remove",
                           in_article_link_title = "remove")

# very similiar process as the first loop 
# only this time we're visiting articles instead of pages of search results

for(i in 1:nrow(all_results)){

remDr$navigate(all_results$links[i])

# The page seems slow to load, let's let it load for 30 seconds
# therefore this is going to take at least 50 minutes to actually run...

Sys.sleep(30)

news_article_html_sel <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] 



news_article_html_sel %>% read_html()
 

# To find the article text instead you'd need to look for a different
# html node in this section:
# then pull the text using html_text()


links <- news_article_html_sel %>%
                   read_html() %>% 
                    html_nodes("a") %>% 
                   html_attr("href")


titles <- news_article_html_sel %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_text()


single_page_articles <- data.frame(page = all_results[i,"page"],
                                   article_title = all_results[i,"titles"],
                                   article_link = all_results[i,"links"],
                                   in_article_links = links,
                                   in_article_link_title = titles)


all_articles <- rbind(all_articles, single_page_articles)

}

all_articles <- all_articles[-1,]
```